# Codeigniter sql query which is already written in core php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to PHP and Codeigniter and I am working on a small application of matrimonial website.

Thing is that I have a SQL query which is written in simple PHP, MySQL now what I am looking is the same SQL query to be written in Codeigniter style .

Below is the normal SQL query, which needs to be written in Codeigniter style.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    users
WHERE
    IF('$se_ct' != '',
        sect = '$se_ct'
            AND IF('$subsect' != '',
            subsect = '$subsect',
            subsect LIKE '%%'),
        sect LIKE '%%' AND subsect LIKE '%%')
        AND IF('$coun_try' != '',
        country = '$coun_try'
            AND IF('$sta_te' != '',
            state = '$sta_te'
                AND IF('$ci_ty' != '',
                city = '$ci_ty',
                city LIKE '%%'),
            state LIKE '%%' AND city LIKE '%%'),
        country LIKE '%%' AND state LIKE '%%'
            AND city LIKE '%%')
        AND age >= '$age_from'
        AND age <= '$age_to'
        AND IF('$qualification' != '',
        qualification = '$qualification',
        qualification LIKE '%%')
        AND gender = '$look'
        AND status = '1'
```

Thanks for the helpers, guiders, developers.

Comment: have you tried my answer?

Comment: yes but not getting result ...any way thanks for support

Comment: I have edited my answer , May be it will help you.

Comment: has iam new can guide from sratch...

Comment: can you tell me your model name in codeigniter?

Comment: i will post short.  my controller  $data = array(
    'look'             =>$this->input->post('look'),......
   
  );
$look             = $this->input->post('look');........

;

$data['showdata'] = $this->searchmodelresult->login($per_page=3,$look,$age,$age_from,$age_to,$se_ct,$subsect,$coun_try, $sta_te, $ci_ty,$qualification);

Comment: now open your searchmodelresult file and place the code which I have write for codeigniter model...

Comment: ok..Call to undefined method Searchmodelresult::login()

Comment: can help me in skype

Comment: not now, If you need I will do it at evening...

Comment: at what time ....can i have ur gmail id ...u look like expert so looking help from you....if u can provide me maild id iwl post the entire controller model and view page

Comment: angelinfotech7777@gmail.com

Comment: please accept and upvote answer if you satisfy with it....

Comment: done now ok....need  a harsh

Comment: Do up vote also...

Comment: done dear ....wts abtur gmailid

Comment: that my mail id and you just accept the answer not up voted...

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like this also in codeigniter

```
    $this->db->query("SELECT *
    FROM users
    WHERE  
    if('$se_ct'!='',sect =  '$se_ct'
    AND 
    if('$subsect' !='',subsect =  '$subsect',subsect like  '%%'),
    sect like  '%%' AND subsect like  '%%')
    AND
    IF( '$coun_try' !='', country =  '$coun_try'
    AND 
    if('$sta_te' !='', state =  '$sta_te'
    AND  
    if('$ci_ty' !='',city =  '$ci_ty',city like  '%%'),state LIKE  '%%'
    AND city LIKE  '%%'), country LIKE  '%%'
    AND state LIKE  '%%'
    AND city LIKE  '%%' ) 
    AND age >=  '$age_from'
    AND age <=  '$age_to'
    AND 
    IF('$qualification' !='',qualification =  '$qualification',  qualification LIKE  '%%' ) 
    AND gender =  '$look'
    And status='1'");

   //for echo the last executed query 
    $this->db->last_query();


   //for returning the result from model to controller     
    return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: I don't know about codeigniter, but injecting variables in a query like that is (almost...) never a good idea.

Comment: echo the query using $this->db->last_query() and run it in phpmyadmin

Comment: the same query fetches  a single record why not here...i know my question  is so poor

Comment: below the sql i had written $query1=$this->db->query($query);
$data['results']=$query1->result();

Comment: $data['showdata']   =   $this->searchmodelresult->login($per_page=3,$look,$age,$age_from,$age_to,$se_ct,$subsect,$coun_try, $sta_te, $ci_ty,$qualification);
$this->load->view('results',$data);  is it correct way

Comment: just eddited answer please check

Comment: yes it looks like the correct way , by the way you can send an array to model rather than sending all the variable in function

Comment: here is my model name

Comment: actually what does null mean in php

Answer (score 0):

You can use these pure Codeigniter :-

Code for Codeigniter Model :-

```
function get_result()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    if ($se_ct != "")
    {
        $this->db->where('sect', $se_ct); 
        if ($subsect != "")
        {
            $this->db->where('subsect', $subsect);  
        }
        else
        {
            $this->db->like('subsect', "");     
        }
    }

    if($coun_try != "")
    {
        $this->db->where('coutry', $count_try); 
        if ($sta_te != "")
        {
            $this->db->where('state', $sta_te);         
            if ($ci_ty != "")
            {
                $this->db->where('city', $ci_ty);               
            }
            else
            {
                $this->db->like('city', ""); 
            }
        }   
        else
        {
            $this->db->like('state', ""); 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->like('country', ""); 
    }


    $this->db->where(array('age >=' => $age_from, 'age <=' => $age_to));

    if ($qualification != "")
    {
        $this->db->where('qualification', $qualification); 
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->like('qualification', ""); 
    }

    $this->db->where('gender', $look); 
    $this->db->where('status', 1); 

    $this->db->from('users');

    return $this->db->get();
}
```

Code for Codeigniter controller :-

```
$data['user'] = $this->user_model->get_result(); // take model as per your code

$this->load->view('user', $data); // take view file as per your code
```

Comment: Thans for the support ...has iam after this how to pass this to  econtroller and from controller to view...please help me and once gain thanks for support

Answer (score 0):

You can write the query as follows

```
return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users
WHERE  
if('$se_ct'!='',sect =  '$se_ct'
AND 
if('$subsect' !='',subsect =  '$subsect',subsect like  '%%'),
sect like  '%%' AND subsect like  '%%')
AND
IF( '$coun_try' !='', country =  '$coun_try'
AND 
if('$sta_te' !='', state =  '$sta_te'
AND  
if('$ci_ty' !='',city =  '$ci_ty',city like  '%%'),state LIKE  '%%'
AND city LIKE  '%%'), country LIKE  '%%'
AND state LIKE  '%%'
AND city LIKE  '%%' ) 
AND age >=  '$age_from'
AND age <=  '$age_to'
AND 
IF('$qualification' !='',qualification =  '$qualification',  qualification LIKE  '%%' ) 

AND gender =  '$look'

And status='1'")->result();
```

Comment: Please check your Method written your controller and Model and check passing arguments. Thank You..

Comment: If it returns Multiple row then write
 return $this->db->query("Your Query")->result();

If it returns single row
 return $this->db->query("Your Query")->row();

and In Controller you can print the result like 
echo "<pre>";
print_r($returnFromModel);
echo "<pre>";

Comment: $data['showdata']   =   $this->searchmodelresult->login($per_page=3,$look,$age,$age_from,$age_to,$se_ct,$subsect,$coun_try, $sta_te, $ci_ty,$qualification);
$this->load->view('results',$data); in view page i had written echo  "<pre>"; echo var_dump($result);for this iamgetting o/p as null

Comment: Try This 
$result=$data['showdata'] = $this->searchmodelresult->login($per_page=3,$look,$age,$age_from,$age_to,$se_ct,‌​$subsect,$coun_try, $sta_te, $ci_ty,$qualification);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre">
exit;

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cikk\application\controllers\search.php on line 38

Comment: $result=$data['showdata'] = $this->searchmodelresult->login($per_page=3,$look,$age,$age_from,$age_to,$se_ct,‌​‌​$subsect,$coun_try, $sta_te, $ci_ty,$qualification); echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); echo "</pre">; exit;

Comment: Message:  Undefined variable: result

Comment: $result=$data['showdata'] = $this->searchmodelresult->login($per_page=3,$look,$age,$age_from,$age_to,$se_ct,$subsect,$coun_try, $sta_te, $ci_ty,$qualification);
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($result);
 echo "</pre>";
 exit;

?? Is nothing. its a mistake while i copy from your comment.